# How to get pdf files in Solidity?

Tags: project, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, verify

I'm making a student management system project in Blockchain, where I use solidity to develop it.

I want to add transcripts, certificates by the owner. So how do I get pdf files in solidity and how to verify it?

Also, how can I share this with another owner in the node?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot really get pdf from solidity or store them on blockchain. Following are the ways you can solve your problem:

1. Generate a sha256 hash for the pdf and upload that hash onto the chain. Whenever someone wants to verify if they have the correct pdf, they just check the hash of the pdf is correct.(recommend)
2. Create an external service on web servers(Oracle) that verifies the pdf and pushes the result to blockchain. Whenever someone wants to verify the pdf, they upload the link to smart contract, external service is monitoring that contract for new transactions. Whenever one arrives they pick up link, verify the pdf and push the results to the smart contract which update the state of that pdf file

Comment: If I want to retrieve those certificates,how do I make it? SHA256 is irreversible !

Comment: Can I store pdf in BigchainDB?

Comment: Yeah you can do that but you can't access directly in solidity. You will have to use an Oracle that fetches and stores files in it

Comment: Ethereum was not designed to store files but transactions. You can use many other decentralised solutions like IPFS for this